# SQL Slow in code not SSMS

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am running into issues working with a very large table from C# .Net 4.0.

For reference the table has ~120 Million rows.

I can't do even a simple query like

```
SELECT TOP(50) * 
FROM TableName 
WHERE CreatedOn < '2015-06-01';
```

From code it will timeout (Default setting - 15 seconds I believe), but in SSMS it is instant.

There is an index on the column in the WHERE clause.  I have also tried explicitly casting the string to a DateTime, and using a DateTime parameter instead of a literal value.

I tried a different query that filters by the PK (bigint, identity, clustered index) If I do something like "Where TableRowID = 1" it works fine from code, but if I try to use "<" or "<=" instead it will timeout (returns instantly in SSMS), regardless of how many rows are turned.

The execution plans are very simple and are **exactly the same**. 
I have tried changing ARITHABORT but that has had no effect.
I tried having the Application connect with my own account (SSPI) instead of its own credentials with no effect.

I have been researching this issue for a few days, but everything I have found blames different execution plans.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this issue?

The .Net code looks like this:

```
private DataSet ExecuteQuery(string query, string db, List<SqlParameter> parms = null)
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[db].ToString();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString.Trim());
    SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        if (parms != null)
        {
            foreach (SqlParameter p in parms)
            {
                sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(p);
            }
        }

        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(ds);

        if (ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            return ds;
        }

        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (sqlDataAdapter != null)
            sqlDataAdapter.Dispose();
        if (con != null)
            con.Dispose();
    }
}
```

The error message I get in .Net is the standard timeout message:

```
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
```

Comment: `Top` keyword without `order by` doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: Can you show a bit of the C# code around you SQL ?

Comment: You've read this?   http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Comment: The query plans between code and SSMS are EXACTLY the same.

Comment: How do you know what execution plan is being used when you run it from code?   Is there a way to see it that I don't know about?

Comment: how many columns are you returning?  what are their types?  seems likely  that it isn't the query that is slow from c#, its the work happening inside the sqlDataAdapter.Fill(ds) call.

Comment: Is machine running SSMS the same machine that runs C# code you have pasted? ... if they are not the same, then you may go different network route and have problem at this level

Comment: I looked up the plans for both in the plan cache. I have even made minor variations (such as change it to TOP(51) or adding AND 1=1) to verify I am looking at the correct plan(s).

Comment: Yes. Same machine is running code and SSMS

Comment: Geoff - the issue occurs even if I query for a single column (PK) and/or no rows are returned.

Comment: why do you need this check...?  if (ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            return ds;
        } 
just return ds and you can check in the debugger if the ds has tables[0] filled with data or not.. there is also a better way to check for empty rows as well

Comment: if you want to check to see if any rows have truly been returned do the following:
`public bool CastandCheckForNoRecords(DataSet ds)
        {
            bool hasRows = ds.Tables.Cast<DataTable>().Any(table => table.Rows.Count != 0);
            if (hasRows)
            {
                dtInvoice = ds.Tables[0];
            }
            return hasRows;
        }`

Comment: Can you paste the exception details that you have from C# code?

Comment: you say its fast when returning a single row, but slow when there are more? Does Top(1) perform the same as Where TableRowID=1?

Comment: TOP(1) still produces a timeout in code

Answer (score 0):

Here are my experience when dealing the issues.
Very C# sql code passed to sql server is 
SELECT TOP(50) * 
FROM TableName 
WHERE CreatedOn < '2015-06-01'

Make sure the criteria. If it takes "instant time" to retrieve records on SSMS, the sql statement and db optimization is ok.

As other people have pointed out, you should post your C# codes and see what happens. There could be other issues. Could that be network? Could that be web.config? Do you call directly from C# code? Do you call via web service?

when you said time out? Does it time out at the time you execute the query. There is very little information you provide. Do you use third party routines (such as written by vendor or your company) to execute queries? If it possible, put the break point at the code that execute sql statement. What I mean is dig all the way to native codes, and put the break codes.

120 million records. Looks like the database has be optimized if it runs very fast on SSMS. I would take look outside SQL server.

good luck

Answer (score 0):

My first step there would be to look at what your code is sending to the sql server. I'd begin by running the sql profiler. if you're not familiar with it. Here is a link on how to use it.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2040/use-sql-server-profiler-to-trace-database-calls-from-third-party-applications/

After this you may want to look into network traffic times between the 2 servers.

Then look at IIS and see how it's setup. Could be a setting is wrong.

Check the error logs and see if you have any errors as well.

Comment: I don't have the necessary privileges to run Profiler, but .Net and SSMS are running on the same computer.

Comment: That's tough. It's hard to know exactly what's going on without that. is it possible for you to duplicate the setup in an environment you can control so you can run the profiler?

Comment: I don't have the necessary permissions even in our Dev environment - but the issue only exists in production anyway. However, I have started to have some issues in SSMS as well - so I am starting to think the issue may be on the DB side.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute code in SSMS, the system is setting some default values on your connection. Specifically, look at Tools --> Options --> Query Execution --> Sql Server --> Advanced (and also ANSI). These statements are executed on your behalf when you open a new query window.

When you create your connection object in C#, are you setting these same options? If you don't explicitly set them here, you are taking the default values as defined in the actual SQL Server instance. In SSMS, you can get this by viewing the properties of the server instance and choosing the Connections page. This shows the default connection options.

You can also get this information without using the UI (you can do this in a separate application that uses the same connection string, for example). This article on [MSSQLTips](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1415/determining-set-options-for-a-current-session-in-sql-server/) should guide you in the right direction.

Comment: The only difference is ARITHABORT, which I have already tried changing and that didn't help.

Comment: Are you running your statement within a transaction in your C# code? That's the only other thing that I can think of that would make an identical statement running under identically configured connections (including network library, packet size, and all those default options) behave differently. SSMS doesn't do anything that your application can't do. It's just another client connecting to the server.

Comment: No, I am not doing any transactions - however I am starting to see issues in SSMS now so I am wondering if the issue doesn't lie on the DB side.